# Cant install scikit-learn on Rapsberry Pi 4

Tags: pi-4

Installed all dependencies from various other answers related to the same question. Did not work.
changed the tmp directory (due to the no Space Available error) still throws same error.

```
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpmzwbrc07_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmplza93os8
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ue3qlcx0/scipy_b579475e795f43738272b74699bdfa2c
    Complete output (45 lines):
    + meson setup /tmp/pip-install-ue3qlcx0/scipy_b579475e795f43738272b74699bdfa2c /tmp/pip-install-ue3qlcx0/scipy_b579475e795f43738272b74699bdfa2c/.mesonpy-miaraila/build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --native-file=/tmp/pip-install-ue3qlcx0/scipy_b579475e795f43738272b74699bdfa2c/.mesonpy-miaraila/build/meson-python-native-file.ini
    The Meson build system
    Version: 1.2.0
    Source dir: /tmp/pip-install-ue3qlcx0/scipy_b579475e795f43738272b74699bdfa2c
    Build dir: /tmp/pip-install-ue3qlcx0/scipy_b579475e795f43738272b74699bdfa2c/.mesonpy-miaraila/build
    Build type: native build
    Project name: SciPy
    Project version: 1.11.1
    C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 10.2.1 "cc (Raspbian 10.2.1-6+rpi1) 10.2.1 20210110")
    C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.35.2
    C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (gcc 10.2.1 "c++ (Raspbian 10.2.1-6+rpi1) 10.2.1 20210110")
    C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.35.2
    Cython compiler for the host machine: cython (cython 0.29.36)
    Host machine cpu family: arm
    Host machine cpu: arm
    Program python found: YES (/usr/bin/python3)
    Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (0.29.2)
    Run-time dependency python found: YES 3.9
    Program cython found: YES (/tmp/pip-build-env-85wnsvgp/overlay/bin/cython)
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-but-set-variable: YES
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-unused-function: YES
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-conversion: YES
    Compiler for C supports arguments -Wno-misleading-indentation: YES
    Library m found: YES
    Fortran compiler for the host machine: gfortran (gcc 10.2.1 "GNU Fortran (Raspbian 10.2.1-6+rpi1) 10.2.1 20210110")
    Fortran linker for the host machine: gfortran ld.bfd 2.35.2
    Compiler for Fortran supports arguments -Wno-conversion: YES
    Checking if "-Wl,--version-script" : links: YES
    Program pythran found: YES (/tmp/pip-build-env-85wnsvgp/overlay/bin/pythran)
    Found CMake: /usr/bin/cmake (3.18.4)
    WARNING: CMake Toolchain: Failed to determine CMake compilers state
    Run-time dependency xsimd found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)
    Run-time dependency threads found: YES
    
    ../../scipy/meson.build:48:17: ERROR: Command `/usr/bin/python3 -c 'import os
    os.chdir(os.path.join("..", "tools"))
    import numpy as np
    try:
      incdir = os.path.relpath(np.get_include())
    except Exception:
      incdir = np.get_include()
    print(incdir)
      '` failed with status 1.
    
    A full log can be found at /tmp/pip-install-ue3qlcx0/scipy_b579475e795f43738272b74699bdfa2c/.mesonpy-miaraila/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a6/98/fceb84466a74b8fe74ce2dcc3a0a89cb7b4a689d4775e0fb4c95f335ef6a/scipy-1.11.1.tar.gz#sha256=fb5b492fa035334fd249f0973cc79ecad8b09c604b42a127a677b45a9a3d4289 (from https://pypi.org/simple/scipy/) (requires-python:<3.13,>=3.9). Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /tmp/tmpmzwbrc07_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /tmp/tmplza93os8 Check the logs for full command output.
  Downloading scipy-1.10.1.tar.gz (42.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 42.4 MB 4.0 kB/s 
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

Comment: what size SD card are you using? Or more importantly, how much free space is available before trying the install?

Comment: SD card is of size 8GB and it shows about 400MB of free space left

Comment: Welcome.  How are you checking the free space?  Also, have you "Check[ed] the logs for full command output", as per the warning right before the (last) error? (Presumably those are where "a full log can be found...").